# ProtoBuf type casting problem

Tags: class, casting, protobuf-net

I use ProtoBuf to serialize class which is created at runtime using Activator.CreateInstance.
Unfortunately Serializer.Deserialize method gives error "Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: System.Object". Any hint how to solve this.

```
var converterName = "Passing class name as string"
var type = Type.GetType(converterName);
            var yourObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type) 
            if (yourObject != null)
            {

                FillRequest(Request.Params, yourObject);
                var com = new CommunicationLayer();
                yourObject = com.Submit(yourObject);
                FillResponse(yourObject);
            }

public class CommunicationLayer
{
public T Submit<T>(T engine)
{
<code skip>
 Serializer.Serialize(stream, engine); //Works fine
<code skip>

  engine = Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream); //Gives error

<code skip>
}
}
```

I have choose to create and cast class at runtime from string because converterName variable parameter is passed in ASP.NET app and such classes will be about 100. Yes, I could replace the whole code with 100 If's

```
If converterName=="MyClass1"
{
 var yourObject = new MyClass1();
 FillRequest(Request.Params, yourObject);
                var com = new CommunicationLayer();
                yourObject = com.Submit(yourObject);
                FillResponse(yourObject);
}
  Else  
If converterName=="MyClass2"
{
 var yourObject = new MyClass2();
 FillRequest(Request.Params, yourObject);
                var com = new CommunicationLayer();
                yourObject = com.Submit(yourObject);
                FillResponse(yourObject);
}
  Else  
....
```

but I would like to have less code if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the generic method is inferring T=object.

There is a non-generic API intended for this scenario; look at Serializer.NonGeneric.*

Or in v2, everything under TypeModel/RuntimeTypeModel (where all the "real" code now is) is *also* non-generic throughout.

If you are doing this lots, I recommend using v2. In v1 the generic code is the "primary", with the non-generic code using reflection to shim into the generic code via `MakeGenericMethod()` (relatively expensive). In v2 this is reversed: the non-generic code is the "primary", and the generic methods shim into the non-generic API via `typeof(T)`.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages of the use of Serializer.NonGeneric class?

Comment: @Tomas none whatsoever; in *regular* code it is a little less convenient (as you might need to give some methods a `Type` instance ad a cast or two, etc), but for what you are doing - it is the intended API.